# jQuery Cloned Form Fields Vanishing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am duplicating a section of a form with the code that follows. Unfortunately, the copied fields appear for a split-second before 'vanishing'. Does anyone see any glaring error that may be causing this?

**jQuery Copy Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $( '#addButton' ).bind( 'click', function()
    {
        var $clone = $( '.template' ).clone();

        $clone.removeClass( 'template' );
        $clone.appendTo( '.LHS_interior' );
    });
});

</script>
```

**Template**

```
<!-- class 'template' is simply 'display:none;' -->
<div class="template">

        <div style="position:relative; float:left; width:50%;">

            <label for="billable_task">Charge Number:</label>
            <select name="billable_task" id="billable_task" onchange="resetSelect('unbillable_task');enable('submit');">

                ...

            </select>   
        </div>

        <div style="position:relative; float:right; width:45%;">

            <label for="duration">Duration:</label>
            <input size="5" type="text" name="duration" id="duration" />

        </div>

</div>
```

**Insert Location**

```
<div style="position:relative; float:left; width:25%;">

    <div class="LHS_interior"></div>

    <button id="addButton" type="button" class="button add">Add Charge</button>

</div>
```

---

So are there any glaring issues with this code?

Comment: Do you have a working example we can see?

Comment: unrelated to the answer, but you're cloning form fields and not changing the `id`.  might want to change that.

Comment: @David Wick +1, cloning anything and not changing the `id` is bad news, form field or not. But he might want to change their `name` as well since he's not cloning any `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yea, I still need to update the field ids, but was wanting to get the basics of the clone working first. @kingjiv unfortunately this is being worked on currently in a closed network where I am employed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out after hours of messing with it.

The reason the code posted in the original message worked is because, well it was correct. It seems when I was typing the code into the post I had entered it differently than what was present in my working code. What was the difference?

```
<button id="addButton" type="button" class="button add">Add Charge</button>
```

In my working code it is:

```
<button id="addButton" class="button add">Add Charge</button>
```

The problem was that I was testing in Chrome and Firefox. These browsers set the default type for a button as **submit** and not **button** ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp))

Because of this my form was submitting every time I added the new fields and then it would reset.

A simple mistake that I kept overlooking. Its not the first time it has happened and definitely will not be the last.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not caused by something else? I copied and pasted your code into jsfiddle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/ejWwM/2/

Although I don't the it lays them out quite the way you want it definitely clones each template

Answer (score 1):

Running it on this jsFiddle works properly (styling is bad though). http://jsfiddle.net/4qtcP/

My guess is that you have some styling that is bumping the float or positioning it outside of the boundaries of a parent container that has overflow: hidden;.

You may want to edit that jsfiddle with more of your CSS.